# クラスからメソッドを呼び出すには？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
    class sample
    {
        public void sample_method()
        {
            テスト(); //呼び出しエラー
        }
    }

    public void テスト()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("呼び出し完了");
    }
```

この場合、テストメソッドを呼び出すにはどのように記述すればよいでしょうか？
visual studio express 2015 (windows 10 64bit)

Comment: クラス（等）に所属しないメソッド（関数）はC#では書けなかったと思います。つまりこのようなテストメソッドはそもそも記述できません（と思います。確認下さい）どこかのクラスの静的メソッドとして記述します。

Answer (score -2):

```
class sample
{
    public void sample_method()
    {
        テスト(); //呼び出しエラー
    }

    public void テスト()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("呼び出し完了");
    }
}
```

こういうこと？
別クラスにあるメソッドを呼びたいということ？